# Raspberry pi unable to allocate memory error when training a model

Tags: memory

I'm trying to train a model on my raspberry pi 4 B 8gb and numpy can not allocate memory -- it needs 1.09 gb. I went digging online and haven't found anything useful. Vcgencmd get_mem gives me 948M for arm and 76M for GPU. Also there is no mention of memory in config.txt. What is the fix to this?
Increasing swapfile to 4096M and memory in settings to 896M caused a fatal error (rip compiled opencv).

Comment: Welcome. *"It needs 1.09 gb"* -> You might want to clarify where you got this number from.  Also, if the training runs at all, check the output of `free -h` and edit it into your post.

Comment: Open a shell and run `ulimit -a`.  What is the max memory size reported?